# Output Location of Element

Tags: tex-core

Suppose I have a LaTeX document, the entirety of whose content is:

```
$\frac{a+b}{c}$
```

Now, suppose I want to bounding rectangles for the $a$, $b$, and $c$. Is there a way to DEFINE A FUNCTION "bbox" so that I can change my LaTeX code to:

```
$\frac{\bbox{id_a}{a} + \bbox{id_b}{b}}{\bbox{id_c}{c}}$
```

and then, as part of the output, I get:

```
id_a: BBOX INFO
id_b: BBOX INFO
id_c: BBOX INFO
```

Thanks!

== Response to Comments:

Comment 1: Where should the BBOX INFO be output to?
Answer: Outputting the BBOX INFO into *any location*, as long as it's (1) consistent and (2) machine parseable, is fine.

Comment 2: Where does the BBOX INFO come from?
Answer: When TeX runs, each character/sub expression is stuck in a BBOX. That is the BBOX I want outputted, i.e. the x_min, x_max, y_min, y_max relative to the page.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Where is the output `id_a: BBOX INFO`, `id_b: BBOX INFO`, and `id_c: BBOX INFO` supposed to go to -- the pdf file, the log file, or some other place?

Comment: This still seems incredibly vague. The command `\typeout{stuff}` writes "stuff" to the terminal and to the `.log` file, so you could redefine `\frac` to be composed of commands named `\bbox`, which, in turn, include the command `\typeout`.  But I doubt that is what you want...  And why is any of this "relative to the page"? What page?

Comment: (relative to the page the formula is outputted on)

Comment: @JohnKormylo : I was vague. I want to define a function bbox with the property that the bbox info is outputted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Box dimensions

The material of `\bbox` can be put into a box and the dimensions of the box can be output. However, math mode is especially difficult, because the math style is not known. This can be partially solved by `\mathpalette` (`\mathchoice`), where the box is set in all four math styles and TeX then selects the right one. The output must then be done via deferred `\write` at shipout time, `\immediate\write` would output the result for all four math styles.

There are some restrictions:

- The nature of the math atom changes, thus `\bbox` must be surrounded by `\mathbin`, `\mathrel`, ... according to the boxed contents.
- Cramped style is not detected (it matters for superscripts in denominators or in roots).

### Position

pdfTeX (LuaTeX, XeTeX) has a feature `\pdfsavepos` to remember the current position. It works in both modes DVI and PDF. Since the position is known at page shipout time, it can only be used to write the position to auxiliary files.

Limitations:

- The position is fine for relative positions, when there is a reference point, then the distances to this point can be measured. The positions are output in scaled points (`sp`) without unit.
- AFAIK the feature is not usable with XeTeX with mixed left-right and right-left modes. It messes up the positions.

### Example

The following example writes the box dimensions and the positions into the `.aux` file, where they can be evaluated further:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{zref-savepos}

\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand{\bbox}[2]{%
  \ifmmode
    \mathpalette{\bbox@math{#1}}{#2}%
  \else
    \@bbox{#1}{#2}%
  \fi
}
\newcommand{\bbox@math}[3]{%
% #1: id
% #2: math style
% #3: box contents
  \@bbox{#1}{$#2#3\m@th$}%
}
\newcommand{\@bbox}[2]{%
  \begingroup
    \sbox0{\zsavepos{bbox-#1}#2}%
    \usebox{0}%
    \if@filesw
      \protected@write\@auxout{}{%
        \string\bboxaux{#1}{\the\wd0}{\the\ht0}{\the\dp0}%
      }%
    \fi
  \endgroup
}
\usepackage{auxhook}
\AddLineBeginAux{%
  \string\providecommand\string\bboxaux[4]{}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\bbox{id_hello}{Hello}
$\bbox{id_frac}{%
  \frac{
    \bbox{id_a}{a}
    \mathbin{\bbox{id_plus}{+}}
    \bbox{id_b}{b}
  }{
    \bbox{id_c}{c}
  }
}$
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

The `.aux` file:

```
\relax
\providecommand\zref@newlabel[2]{}
\providecommand\bboxaux[4]{}
\zref@newlabel{bbox-id_hello}{\posx{9782558}\posy{46515936}}
\bboxaux{id_hello}{22.50005pt}{6.94444pt}{0.0pt}
\zref@newlabel{bbox-id_frac}{\posx{11475574}\posy{46515936}}
\zref@newlabel{bbox-id_a}{\posx{11554217}\posy{46773972}}
\bboxaux{id_a}{4.33765pt}{3.01389pt}{0.0pt}
\zref@newlabel{bbox-id_plus}{\posx{11838489}\posy{46773972}}
\bboxaux{id_plus}{6.13892pt}{4.33334pt}{0.83334pt}
\zref@newlabel{bbox-id_b}{\posx{12240809}\posy{46773972}}
\bboxaux{id_b}{3.51666pt}{4.8611pt}{0.0pt}
\zref@newlabel{bbox-id_c}{\posx{11895643}\posy{46289942}}
\bboxaux{id_c}{3.57375pt}{3.01389pt}{0.0pt}
\bboxaux{id_frac}{16.39322pt}{8.79842pt}{3.44841pt}
```

Comment: Suppose vertical mode. Then `\hbox{x}next text` and `\bbox{id}{\hbox{x}}next text` gives different results.

Comment: @wipet Then replace `\usebox{0}` by `\copy0\relax`. But `\hbox` is plain TeX, LaTeX users are supposed to use `\mbox`.

Answer (score 5):

You can try following macros:

```
\newwrite\fbbox
\immediate\openout\fbbox=\jobname.box

\def\bbox#1#2{#2\def\bboxid{#1}%
   \ifmmode \mathpalette\bboxM{#2}\else \bboxA{#2}\fi
}
\def\bboxA#1{\setbox0=\hbox{#1}\pdfsavepos\bboxB}
\def\bboxM#1#2{\setbox0=\hbox{$#1#2$}\pdfsavepos\bboxB}
\def\bboxB{\edef\tmp{\write\fbbox
      {\bboxid: (\noexpand\the\pdflastxpos, \noexpand\the\pdflastypos)
      [\number\wd0, \number\ht0, \number\dp0]}}\tmp}

%% tests:
Normal text: \bbox{id_g}{g}

${a+b \over c} = d + e$

${\bbox{id_a}{a}+ \bbox{id_b}{b} \over \bbox{id_c}{c}} =
 \bbox{id_d}{d} + \bbox{id_e}{e}$
```

The absolute position is printed using pdfTeX primitive `\pdfsavepos`. The output file `document.box` includes the data in the form:

```
id1: (8577430, 49989344) [327681, 282168, 127431]
id_a: (6409921, 48592804) [284272, 197518, 0]
id_b: (7042709, 48592804) [230468, 318577, 0]
id_c: (6701284, 48108774) [234209, 197518, 0]
id_d: (8336264, 48334768) [341106, 455111, 0]
id_e: (9442407, 48334768) [305153, 282168, 0]
```

Formally: `box_id: (posx, posy) [wd, ht, dp]`, where `(posx, posy)` is the position after the letter or box is printed and `[wd, ht, dp]` is width, height and depth of the letter or box. The used unit is sp = 1/2^16 pt.

I suppose that you will read such data by another program. It can calculate
bounding box like:

```
Left-bottom corner: (posx - wd, posy - dp)
Top-right corner:   (posx, posy + ht)
```

I must point out that the result cannot be exactly true in math mode, because

```
$$ {a\over e^2}, {a\over \hbox{$e^2$}} $$
```

gives a slight different result for e^2, but if you will measure e^2 then the macro measures the second but prints the first.

Comment: I regret not being able to accept two answers. (And upvote neither. :-)).

Comment: @notenote What solution is more simple? Where you can simply write `\bbox{plus}{+}` without a specification about `\mathbin`? Where the output is prepared in unique unit (sp) so you needn't recalculate unit before BoundixBox calculation? What output is more simple, able to be scanned by an external program?

Comment: Which solution uses $\frac{a+b}{c}$? The problem opened with the words »Suppose I have a LaTeX document...«

Comment: @wipet very useful recipe! Sorry for a newbie question, but how would one go at evaluating the corner positions right away, so outputting (posx - wd, posy - dp)? I've tried a bunch of recipes for length recalculation, but they seem to fail inside this command.